# Websphere 8.5 jdk 7 installation

Tags: websphere, ibm-jdk

I have JDK 7 installed on my machine.
I have JDK 7 patch installed on Websphere 8.5.5.0

When I try to run the following command I get an error.

Command
**managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv01 -sdkName 1.7_64**

Error
***CWSDK0009E: Unexpected exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: CWLCA0012E: The sdk 1.7_64 is not available on node XXXXXX***

where XXXXXX is my node name.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

PS: Listing does tell me that I've JDK 7 installed.
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin>managesdk -listAvailable

CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
**CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64

CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_64**
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

Comment: Try to list profiles using `managesdk.bat -listAvailable` to see what is installed. I'd also suggest to update 8.5.5.0 to the latest patch.

Comment: I did. Listing profiles does show JDK 7 but enabling is still not happening.  C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin>managesdk -listAvailable
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_64
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

Comment: Did you check that page - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM88565 . If your profile is federated you need to restart node agent and ensure dmgr is running; in case of single server, the server should be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to /bin and execute below command.

Win: managesdk.bat -listAvailable -verbose
AIX: managesdk.sh -listAvailable -verbose

You will get output as for AIX:

CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.1.6_64=1.6
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.1.6_64=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.1.6_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.1.6_64=aix
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.1.6_64=ppc_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.1.6_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/aix/ppc_64/

CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.1.7_64=1.7
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.1.7_64=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.1.7_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java_1.7_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.1.7_64=aix
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.1.7_64=ppc_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.1.7_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/aix/ppc_64/

Check for location.1.7_64 path and make sure the path is present.

Also make sure your AppServer dir has all file permissions for all users.

once you do that execute below mentioned commands.

AIX: managesdk.sh -setCommandDefault -sdkname 1.7_64
WIN: managesdk.sh -setCommandDefault -sdkname 1.7_64

AIX: managesdk.sh -setNewProfileDefault -sdkname 1.7_64
WIN: managesdk.sh -setNewProfileDefault -sdkname 1.7_64

AIX: managesdk.sh -enableProfileAll -sdkname 1.7_64 -enableServers
WIN: managesdk.sh -enableProfileAll -sdkname 1.7_64 -enableServers

Check now..!!

Cheers..!!